# what kind of password protection is suitable for admin interface?

Tags: security, user-interface, passwords, admin, password-protection

I have a project where the developer is building for me an admin interface that can be accessed from my domain, e.g.: `domain.com/admin/`.

Which kind of password protection should such an interface have?

1. Simply put password protection on the `/admin/` folder via Cpanel, which basically I Can do on my own.
2. Make a built-in login screen for the interface.

Is there any difference? what are the considerations?

Answer (score 0):

One way to protect your admin interface would be:

- Implement an access control restriction on the /admin url patterns, only those logged in as admin can access URLs containing this suffix
- Check in every page/view which is contained in the /admin folder whether the user is an administrator and has the right credentials
- Depending on your framework, implement good security practices like store only passwords in an encrypted form, prevent security leaks, implement session handling in a secure way, use already-made viable security tools(like PHP password_hash)